# Expected value of exponential transformation of poisson

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let X be a poisson distributed variable with parameter $\lambda$. I would like to calculate the expectation of $E[e^{-ax}]$, where $a$ is a constant. I use the Taylor series approximation as follows, although I get a really ugly result. Is there a better way to solve it so that the answer is more convenient?

$$ E[e^{-ax}] = \sum_{i=0}^\infty e^{-ai}\frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^i}{i!} = e^{-\lambda}\sum_{i=0}^\infty  \frac{ (\lambda/e^a)^i }{i!} $$

which is the Taylor series for $e^{\lambda/e^a}$. Thus,

$$ E[e^{-ax}] = e^{-\lambda} e^{\lambda/e^a}  $$

Is this correct? or is there a better / more correct way to do it?

Comment: I see nothing wrong with that other than a bunch of typos. (And disagree that it's real ugly. In fact it's one of the most beautiful MGFs out there.)

Comment: Thank you! all typos are fixed

Comment: you still missed one (or two if you count multiplicity).

Comment: (In the sum it should be $i!,$ not $\lambda !$)